# print variables with html tags in asp.net mvc2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i'm new to asp.net mvc . i have a scenario where model passes list of strings some of them contains links in the view files, when i print them it prints as characters and not as html example would be like

```
@{
  var str =  "<a href=\"aa\">aaa</a>";
}
@str
```

when i execute it will print as

```
<a href=\"aa\">aaa</a>
```

how to print it as following???

[aaa](http://aaa)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Actually in razor by default encoding enable.

```
@{
   var str =  "<a href=\"aa\">aaa</a>";
 }
 @Html.Raw(str)
```

This will work.